# Secure Configuration for a C# Service

Tags: c#, service

hopefully this is a simple one and I'm just failing to find the answer!

I want to write a C# application to run as a service that periodically connects to a SQL Server DB to run a few queries. The connection details for the SQL Server must be stored somewhere that the server can get them, but I don't want them stored in a plain text file. I could store them in an encrypted file, but then password would need to be stored somewhere that the service could access it, somewhat defeating the point.

So is there some kind of application/service-level encryption or secure storage API that exists, that allows configuration/data to be stored securely that doesn't need me to just store a password in a file somewhere?

Cheers!

Comment: Usually, connection strings and credentials are stored on the server in a configuration file. Your server should already be secure so storing the account password in plain text should not be an issue. To reduce potential vulnerabilities the you should create an account for your SQL server that has limited permissions and use those credentials in your application.

Comment: @CallbackKid I disagree you should always avoid storing passwords in plain text, if a malicious user infiltrates your webserver having encrypted passwords to other parts of your app db/api etc means they arent necessarily compromised as well. Defense in depth.

Comment: Why are either of you assuming this is on a web server?  The question just says a C# application running as a service...

Comment: Yes, this is nothing to do with a web service. I'm on about a windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to encrypt the app.config (see [this blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file) for some more details).  However, an administrative user (or a user who can attach a debugger to your program, or a user who can set up a proxy between your program and the server if the password isn't sent through encrypted) will be able to see the decrypted password.

If you're concerned about that, you should consider a different security model.  For instance, you could go with a [Trusted Subsystem Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905320.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), in which users authenticate against a intermediary service that is trusted to connect to your database.  This service could be set up to use claims, role, or user based authentication to authenticate users and determine whether they should have access to the database - and would ensure that you never distribute the password stored in your connection string.

Alternatively, if possible, you could consider utilizing logins and users/groups in SQL Server - which would allow you to use trusted authentication and not require a password in the connection string (although it would still require you to distribute the connection string with your application, and again even if it's encrypted a user of your application who has administrative access to the machine could potentially view it decrypted).

Just note that both of these methods do come with some additional overhead - you'll have to maintain roles/claims/users on some level to make sure that only the users you want are able to connect (not as simple as just always accepting the connection from whoever has access to the application).

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for that. If someone has admin access to that machine my service is running on, then all bets are off anyway, so I'm not too concerned about that. I'd come across the DPAPI before I posted my question, but wasn't sure exactly if it was fit for my purpose. It sounds like it is. Nice one!